# Error using libraries provided by CGAL with qt creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator, cgal

I'm currently trying to use the cgal library in a project in qt creator (on windows). I'm all new to this ide and also to c++ but cgal offers some functionality i'd like to test. I tried to run a cgal example in qt creator in order to find out if the library is included correctly. Unfortunately i get the error message: 'enable_if_t' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type. I also get some warnings about an unused but set parameter [error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huTdU.png).

The code i'd like to run is an example from CGAL:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>

typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2 Point_2;
typedef Kernel::Segment_2 Segment_2;

int main()
{
  Point_2 p(1,1), q(10,10);
  std::cout << "p = " << p << std::endl;
  std::cout << "q = " << q.x() << " " << q.y() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "sqdist(p,q) = "
            << CGAL::squared_distance(p,q) << std::endl;

  Segment_2 s(p,q);
  Point_2 m(5, 9);

  std::cout << "m = " << m << std::endl;
  std::cout << "sqdist(Segment_2(p,q), m) = "
            << CGAL::squared_distance(s,m) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "p, q, and m ";
  switch (CGAL::orientation(p,q,m)){
  case CGAL::COLLINEAR:
    std::cout << "are collinear\n";
    break;
  case CGAL::LEFT_TURN:
    std::cout << "make a left turn\n";
    break;
  case CGAL::RIGHT_TURN:
    std::cout << "make a right turn\n";
    break;
  }
  std::cout << " midpoint(p,q) = " << CGAL::midpoint(p,q) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

My .pro file:

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

INCLUDEPATH += C:\dev\CGAL-5.0-beta2\include
INCLUDEPATH += C:\dev\libboost_1_71_0
INCLUDEPATH += C:\dev\libboost_1_71_0\lib64-msvc-14.2
INCLUDEPATH += C:\dev\CGAL-5.0-beta2\auxiliary\gmp\include
INCLUDEPATH += C:\dev\CGAL-5.0-beta2\auxiliary\gmp
INCLUDEPATH += C:\dev\vtk\include\vtk-8.2
INCLUDEPATH += C:\dev\vtk\include

LIBS += C:\dev\libboost_1_71_0\lib64-msvc-14.2
LIBS += C:\dev\vtk\lib
LIBS += C:\dev\CGAL-5.0-beta2\auxiliary\gmp\lib


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: The error seems to suggest that `std::enable_if` is not here (maybe c++11 is not on). Then you have to link with gmp and mpfr. If you are using g++ you must add the flags `-frounding-math`.

Comment: Thank you! Your hint about `std::enable_if` not being there was the right clue. I changed compiler settings and this example does work now.